# HttpWebRequest.Timeout behaviour different in .Net / .Net CF?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

During some tests on multipart upload (using Ethernet) i have found something interesting:

I set a short (17sec) HttpWebRequest.Timeout and simulate a long upload using Thread.Sleep in the loop, where the byte-blocks are written to the server.

On a PC i get the timeout (RequestCanceled) but on .Net CF (Windows CE 5/6 Module) i dont get the timeout.

Does anyone has made the same observation ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the implementation of HttpWebRequest.Timeout in .Net CF does nothing:

```
// from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.dll
public override int Timeout
{
    get { }
    set { }
}
```